# How do I include headers outside of my project directory in makefiles

Tags: c, makefile

This is my makefile but the header files are not included:

```
CC      =gcc
#CFLAGS  =-g
INC=-I/inc/stackheaders.h
OBJFILES= main.o fileOperations.o stackOperations.o
HEADERS = inc/stackheaders.h

TARGET  = stacktest
all: $(TARGET)
$(TARGET): $(OBJFILES)
    $(CC) $(INC)-o $(TARGET) $(OBJFILES) 
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJFILES) $(TARGET)
```

The error I get is:

```
gcc    -c -o main.o main.c
main.c:1:26: fatal error: stackheaders.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Comment: It should be included from your .c file, then you can use "gcc -I/inc". Are you sure your include files are in root of your filesystem?

Comment: the include files are in  root of filesystem

Comment: In that case check GCC manual regarding directory search options, https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the makefile change:

```
INC=-I/inc/stackheaders.h
```

...to:

```
INC=-I/inc
```

...given that the file `stackheaders.h` is in `/inc`.